# Simulating CTRL+C with Sendkeys fails

Tags: c#, registerhotkey

I have an odd problem with Sendkeys, what my application basically should do is that, when I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>J</kbd>, it'll simulate a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> operation (on any windows) to copy some highlighted text, however the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> simulation is not working.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]  
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]  
static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 RegisterHotKey(this.Handle,
 this.GetType().GetHashCode(), 1, (int)'J'); // Here it's waiting for the ALT+J 
}

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) // Function to c
{
 if (m.Msg == 0x0312) // If ALT+J pressed
 {
     Copier(); // .. Simulate CTRL+C (but doesn't work)
 }
 base.WndProc(ref m);
}

public void Copier() // Function to simulate the CTRL+C
{
 Debug.WriteLine("Ok ");
 InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_C); // First way
 SendKeys.Send("^(c)"); // Second way
}
```

Comment: +1 I can reproduce it. `SendKeys.Send("^{INS}");` fails too

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to send a WM\_COPY message that copies text somewhere other than the Clipboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569532/is-it-possible-to-send-a-wm-copy-message-that-copies-text-somewhere-other-than-t)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is happening because when you send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> you already have pressed the <kbd>ALT</kbd> modifier of <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

If you put

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

just before send keys, you'll have time to release <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will work.

Also, if you plan to check when your hotkey is released, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783625/global-hotkey-release-keyup-win32-api).